# Time complexity of this program

Tags: time-complexity

I studied how to find the time complexity of a program. But the way I can understand is only the order. What I mean is I can only distinguish the big O of n^3, n^2, log(n), n, or 1. But I could never understand what O(V+E) or O(N*M) means. I agree that there is lacking in my fundamentals. That's why I want to learn about it. Please provide me some links or websites if you can't explain it here.

One more thing, can anyone give me any basic idea how to find the time complexity of this program?

```
[nRow, nCol, noOfRotation] = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

matrix = [ [0 for j in range(nCol)] for i in range(nRow) ]
for i in range(nRow):
    matrix[i] = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

maxRow = nRow-1
maxCol = nCol-1

start = 0

while start < maxRow and start < maxCol:
    tempMat = []

    for col in range(start, maxCol):
        tempMat.append( matrix[ start ][ col ] )

    for row in range(start, maxRow):
        tempMat.append( matrix[ row ][ maxCol ] )

    for col in range(maxCol, start, -1):
        tempMat.append( matrix[ maxRow ][ col ] )

    for row in range(maxRow, start, -1):
        tempMat.append( matrix[ row ][ start ] )


    length = len(tempMat)
    i = 0
    for col in range(start, maxCol):
        matrix[ start ][ col ] = tempMat[ (i + noOfRotation) % length ]
        i += 1

    for row in range(start, maxRow):
        matrix[ row ][ maxCol ] = tempMat[ (i + noOfRotation) % length ]
        i += 1

    for col in range(maxCol, start, -1):
        matrix[ maxRow ][ col ] = tempMat[ (i + noOfRotation) % length ]
        i += 1

    for row in range(maxRow, start, -1):
        matrix[ row ][ start ] = tempMat[ (i + noOfRotation) % length ]
        i += 1

    start += 1
    maxRow -= 1
    maxCol -= 1

for i in range(nRow):
    for j in range(nCol):
        print(matrix[i][j], end = ' ')
    print('')
```

Problem link: [Matrix Layer Rotation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matrix-rotation-algo/problem)

Comment: Notations like O(N*M) are used when an algorithm has multiple inputs each with independent sizes, or the input has multiple measures of "size" such as the width and height of a matrix; N and M are just different variables measuring those independent sizes. Likewise, O(V + E) usually occurs in graph algorithms where V means the number of vertices and E means the number of edges in the graph.

Comment: @kaya3 yeah, I get it. can you help me finding the time complexity of the code above?